# How to make that grid?

Tags: html, css, grid

Do you know how to make the grid like this?
[image: desired grid layout]

I tried to create that with margins to make white spaces. However, it doesn't work for first `<div>` because it has own height and margin [%].

```css
.block {
  height: 270px;
  width: 47%;
  margin: 1.5%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.blockbig {
  width: 97%;
  margin: 1.5%;
  height: 540px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.blockw {
  width: 97%;
  margin: 1.5%;
  height: 270px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.rectagle {
  height: 550px;
  width: 47%;
  margin: 1.5%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.row1 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

@media (max-width: 1160px) {
  .container {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  #b4 {
    clear: both;
  }
  .block {
    width: 28.83%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row1">
    <div class="">
      <div id="b1" class="rectagle" style="background-color: Beige;">1</div>
      <div id="b2" class="block" style="background-color: orange;">2</div>
      <div id="b6" class="block" style="background-color: blue;">6</div>
    </div>
    <div id="b7" class="blockbig" style="background-color: black;">7</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row1">
    <div id="b3" class="block" style="background-color: black;">3</div>
    <div id="b4" class="block" style="background-color: orange;">4</div>
    <div id="b5" class="blockbig" style="background-color: Aquamarine">5</div>
    <div id="b8" class="blockw" style="background-color: Azure ;">8</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97yp4tqr/)

My attempt looks like this:

[image: my attempt]

I would be nice if it's responsive.
Here is the [template](http://templatesxxx.prv.pl//templates/index.html#slide_up), which I have to convert.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? It's killing me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made that.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#b1 {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 25%;
height: 540px;
}

#b2, #b3, #b4, #b6 {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 25%;
height: 270px;
}

#b5, #b7 {
display: block;
width: 50%;
height: 540px;
}

#b5 {
float: right; 
}

#b7 {
float: left;
} 

#b8 {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 270px;
} 

.row1 {
width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1160px) {

.container {
width: 90%;
}

.container1 {
width: 100%;
 
}

@media (max-width: 850px) {

#b1, #b7 {
height: 428px; 
}

#b2, #b3, #b4, #b6 {
height: 214px;
} 

#b1, #b2, #b3, #b4, #b6 { 
width: calc(100%/3); 
}

#b5, #b8 {
height: 214px;
} 

}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
 
#b1, #b2, #b3, #b4, #b6, #b7, #b5 {
width: 50%;
} 

#b7 {
height: 214px;  
}

#b8 {
width: 100%;
} 
 
}


@media (max-width: 480px) {
 
#b1, #b2, #b3, #b4, #b6, #b7, #b5, #b8 {
width: 100%;
height: 400px; 
} 
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">

<div class="row1">

<div id="b1" class="inline-block" style="background-color: Beige;"><div class="block-content">1</div></div>
<div id="b2" class="inline-block" style="background-color: orange;"><div class="block-content">2</div></div>
<div id="b3" class="inline-block" style="background-color: black;"><div class="block-content">3</div></div>
<div id="b4" class="inline-block" style="background-color: orange;"><div class="block-content">4</div></div>

<div id="b6" class="inline-block" style="background-color: blue;"><div class="block-content">6</div></div>
<div id="b5" class="inline-block" style="background-color: Aquamarine"><div class="block-content">5</div></div>
<div id="b7" class="inline-block" style="background-color: black;"><div class="block-content">7</div></div>
<div id="b8" class="inline-block" style="background-color: Azure ;"><div class="block-content">8</div></div>

</div>
</div>
```

However, with border-box, I do not know how to use padding to add white spaces [10px] around all blocks.

Comment: border: 10px solid #ffffff finally has solved the problem ;)